# Resize-Property not working on IMG-Tag

Tags: html, css, image, wysiwyg, contenteditable

I am just having a strange problem. I am currently creating a simple WYSIWYG-Editor for my website. For this I am simply using a div with contenteditable and some `document.execCommand` commands.

To insert an image I am using a modal which shows an input. After the user clicks on "insert" the file is read as base64 and inserted into my textbox using 
`document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<img class='img-resizable' style='width: " + w + "px; height: " + h + "px;' src='" + reader.result + "'></div>");`

So basically I have a result like this:
`<div class="n-edit-content" contenteditable=""><img class="img-resizable" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" src="...base64" /></div>`

So far everything worked as expected. But now I added the properties `resize: both;` and `overflow: auto;` for the user to be able to resize the image. But it is not working. As soon as I change the img-Tag to a div it works, but then the user is able to write inside of the image.
Is there a trick to this one or did I miss out on something important?

I just tested it in chrome, but since the site is supposed to work on all major browsers I don't feel like I have to test it in another one until it is working in chrome.

Greetings
Neokil

Edit: since some people seem not to understand my question, I will try again to explain. What I want to accomplish is not to have some responsive image. the user should be able to scale the image just by klicking in the right bottom corner and dragging. Just the functionality you get by setting `resize:both` in your css. Problem is, this works for all divs, textboxes,... but I cannot get it to work with img-tags.

Comment: you  can use max-width:100%; it's working on responsive .

Comment: `width:100%` `height:auto` should do the trick